# Subsetting Dataframe within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

If I import a dataset from Shiny using `fileInput`, how could I go about creating this in a reactive form where I can create subsets of the imported dataframe and eventually perform calculations on different rows of the subsetted dataframes? Can I store subsetted dataframes as reactiveValues() and then use them outside of a reactive scenario?

How would I go about accomplishing something like the code below, which would be in an ordinary R Script, where it works successfully?

```
df <- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=",")
attach(df)
df <- df[, c(1, 50:75)]
df[1] <- time
```

I know I can accomplish the following using fileInput, I'm just not sure how I can subset things like this within shiny and make them usable in scenarios like 
`renderPlot` and others. Would `reactive` or `reactiveValues` be the best strategy to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "file1",
      "Choose CSV File",
      multiple = F,
      accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", "text")
    ),
    uiOutput("selectbox")
  ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("contents")))
  )
```

---

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- read.csv(file = input$file1$datapath,
             header = T,
             sep = "\t")
  })

  output$selectbox <- renderUI({
    colnam <- colnames(data())
    selectInput("colsel",
                "Columns Selected",
                c("Please select" = "", colnam),
                multiple = T)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    data()[, c(req(input$colsel))]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Not quite. It would be a singular file input, and the input file would be one single data frame, and then I would like to create smaller subset dataframes from the bigger input file one, all which are reactive, and I can specify and call upon by their row and column numbers. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do a couple calculations with them and be able to use them in reactive scenarios

Comment: Ok. It is hard to understand in words. Can you update your Q on what you tried on the Shiny end ?